# Nvidia 780 TI not showing in Device Manager

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, power-supply

So I got myself a Nvidia 780 TI but it does not seem to work in my computer. I've had it tested at a computer store and works fine in a other setup. But in my computer it does not show up in device manager at all. Not as a unrecognized VGA card or something, but just not at all. I am currently using a:

- 700W OCZ PSU
- msi z77a-g45 MOBO

The GPU lights turn on and the fans start spinning. In Click BIOS ii I can't seen anywhere where it would show if the BIOS sees it. I've updated my:

- BIOS
- Other drivers
- Windows update
- CMOS reset

My ATI Radeon HD 7770 works fine in the same slot, the only thing that changed is that I have one cable from my PSU that isn't stock, I needed to to meet the 6-pin and 8pin req. But using it as a 6 pin for my Radeon it works fine.

Comment: How are you seeing Device Manager if the video adapter isn't being detected? Do you have more than one video adapter installed?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Plugged HDMI into mobo, Intel HD 4000 integrated GPU on there